# Multiplayer game in Phaser - the "script" element could not be loaded

Tags: express, webpack

How do you configure the server for this template ? => https://github.com/nkholski/phaser3-es6-webpack
I'm trying to do it by following this tutorial => https://gamedevacademy.org/create-a-basic-multiplayer-game-in-phaser-3-with-socket-io-part-1/?a=13
I added two dependencies: nodemon and express.
I created the server.js file with the server configuration.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const path = require('path')

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve('index.html'))
})  

server.listen(8081, function() {
   console.log(`Listening on ${server.address().port}`)
})
```

In the package.json file, I added a command to start the server:

```
nodemon src/server/server.js
```

The server starts correctly but the indicated html file can not read the scripts (" The load failed for the "script" element with the source vendor.js and app.js").

Project structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgW2S.png

Comment: Go to the Network tab in browser and look at your script path

Comment: Path is correct, problem is in Phaser configuration with Express and webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by indicate to the folder in which the scripts are located .
In my case it was a folder called 'dev'.
Adding this line solved the problem:

```
app.use('/dev', express.static('dev'))
```